# Printing out all duplicates - Javascript - Alternate solution needed

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

**INSTRUCTIONS**

`Given an array, print out all of the duplicates within that array.`

```
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10];

const result = arr.filter(x => arr.filter(y => y === x).length > 1);

console.log(result);

// 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8
```

So, someone else kindly provided this answer, which I understand, but I'm looking for alternate solution that uses for-loops instead.

I came up with this, but this only returns

`2, 3, 5, 8` instead of the above results that I need.

```
const result2 = () => {
  let newArray = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] === arr[i + 1]) {
      newArray.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
   return newArray
}

console.log(result2(arr));

// 2, 3, 5, 8
```

What am I missing? I need for it to print out all duplicates, not just tell me which ones are duplicates.

Comment: Instead of pushing arr[i], you can push arr[i+1] as well so that both the duplicates are obtained in the new array.

Comment: I just tried `newArray.push(arr[i], arr[i + 1])` and that worked, appreciate that.

Comment: `newArray.push(arr[i], arr[i + 1])` will only work if there are always *exactly two* duplicates, and they are next to each other.

Comment: So, let's say I had this array, `[ 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 7, 2, 1]`, what would i need to do be able to make sure it compares everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current

```
if(arr[i] === arr[i + 1]) {
```

doesn't check whether the previous element was the same (and, even if changed to `|| arr[i] === arr[i - 1]`, will only work on sorted arrays, which has not been stated to be guaranteed).

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10];
const result2 = () => {
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === arr[i + 1] || arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
      newArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(result2(arr));
```

To emulate the existing nested `.filter`, you need to figure out how many matching elements are in the array - iterate over the array again and check how many match:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10];
const result2 = () => {
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count >= 2) {
      newArray.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return newArray
}

console.log(result2(arr));
```

But this has bad computational complexity (`O(N^2)`). I'd prefer to come up with a count of how many times each element occurs ahead of time (`O(N)`):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10];
const result2 = () => {
  const countsByNum = arr.reduce((a, num) => {
    a[num] = (a[num] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (countsByNum[arr[i]] >= 2) {
      newArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray
}

console.log(result2(arr));
```

Comment: ah that makes sense, I appreciate both answers and thanks for providing the time complexity. In either case, would the space complexity be consider to be `O(n)` ?

Comment: Yes, space complexity is always `O(n)`, there's no array-of-array nesting

Comment: What would be a simple explanation as to why it's `O(n)`? I need to be able to explain it to someone and have it make sense

Comment: In the first snippet, at any point in the code, there are only two arrays in memory: `arr` and `newArray`, both of which are of size `n`, worst-case, thus `O(n)`. In the second snippet, there's also a `countsByNum` object, but it also has only `n` maximum key-value pairs, so just like the first snippet, overall space complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: you mentioned that my if statement is off, what would i add to make sure everything is checked?

Comment: So are you saying that if my array is sorted, then I'd be able to use `if ( arr[i] === arr[i + 1] || arr[i] !== arr[i - 1])`?

Comment: Almost, use `===` instead of `!==`

Comment: oh, you had `!==` up above in your comment

Comment: and this wouldn't work for something like this `let arr = [1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10];`, i just tried it and it didn't print the 2's

Answer (score 2):

```
   let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10];
    var mem = {};
    var finalArr = [];
    for(var i = 0, j = arr.length; i< j; i++) {
        if(!mem.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])){
            mem[arr[i]] = [];
        }
        mem[arr[i]].push(arr[i]);
    }

    for(var i in mem) {
        if(mem.hasOwnProperty(i) && mem[i].length > 1) {
            finalArr = [...finalArr, ...mem[i]]
        }
    }
    console.log(finalArr);
```

Hope this helps you !

Comment: This won't work when there are more than two duplicate elements in the input array.

Answer (score 1):

By filtering a sorted array

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 10];

arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

var res = arr.filter((v, i, a) => a[i - 1] === v || a[i + 1] === v);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that sorting has `O(n log n)` time complexity